# LWJGL program gives error "no lwjgl in java.library.path", yet when I look in the manifest it is there

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

So I've been working on a program using LWJGL for quite a while, and have now gotten to the point where I want to be able to show it easily to other people. However, when I try to export it as a runnable jar-file and run it in console, I get the above error.

I have also tried exporting it as a normal jar-file and merging it by using jarsplice, however that gives me an error stating that one of several files is missing (a shader file in this case), however it is where it's supposed to be).

Comment: You probably need to put the natives in the same folder as the jar file you made

Comment: I did that and now I feel silly since that is what it said on the page for LWJGL.  Now however I encounter the same problem I encountered when using jarsplice. I have managed to replicate it by changing a part of my code that looks like this
 `Framework.CURRENT_DATAPATH = "/grwlk/data/";` 
 into something else. I guess that putting it into a jar-file messes with something there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you need to modify the build path. What you have to do is select the lwjgl.jar and click edit for the native location for it. Then select the folder that is holding your natives.